# How to get multiple routes from source to destination using bing maps api in python?

Tags: python, bing-maps, driving-directions

I have written a python code which generates the latitude and longitude of source and destination point. Now I want to get multiple possible routes between the two points. How can I obtain it using bing maps api?
If not possible, what alternatives can I try?

Comment: Show your current code please

Answer (score 0):

From [Bing maps API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/routes/calculate-a-route):

> You can request up to three (3) driving or transit route options
> between two waypoints by using the maxSolutions parameter:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/{travelMode}?wayPoint.1={wayPoint1}&viaWaypoint.2={viaWaypoint2}&waypoint.3={waypoint3}&wayPoint.n={waypointN}&heading={heading}&optimize={optimize}&avoid={avoid}&distanceBeforeFirstTurn={distanceBeforeFirstTurn}&routeAttributes={routeAttributes}&timeType={timeType}&dateTime={dateTime}&maxSolutions={maxSolutions}&tolerances={tolerances}&distanceUnit={distanceUnit}&key={BingMapsKey}
```